# Pygraph - path between two nodes with specific weight

Tags: python, graph, pygraph

I want to find a path in a graph that has connects two nodes and does not use the same node twice. The sum of the weights of the edges must be within a certain range.

I need to implement this in *pygraph*. I'm not sure if there is already an algorithm that I can use for this purpose or not. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  I misunderstood the question initially.  I've corrected my answer.  This functionality isn't built into the `pygraphlib` library, but you can easily implement it.  Consider something like this, which basically gets the shortest path, decides if it's in a predefined range, then removes the edge with the smallest weight, and computes the new shortest path, and repeats.

```
from pygraphlib import pygraph, algo

edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,6),(6,7),(3,5),(4,5),(7,1),(2,5),(5,7)]
graph = pygraph.from_list(edges)

pathList = []
shortestPath = algo.shortest_path(graph, startNode, endNode)
cost = shortestPath[len(shortestPath)-1][1]

while cost <= maxCost:
    if cost >= minCost:
        pathList.append(shortestPath)

    minEdgeWt = float('inf')
    for i in range(len(shortestPath)-1):
        if shortestPath[i+1][1] - shortestPath[i][1] < minEdgeWt:
            minEdgeWt = shortestPath[i+1][1] - shortestPath[i][1]
            edgeNodes = (shortestPath[i][0], shortestPath[i+1][0])

    #Not sure of the syntax here, edgeNodes is a tuple, and hide_edge requires an edge.
    graph.hide_edge(edgeNodes)
    shortestPath = alog.shortest_path(graph, startNode, endNode)
    cost = shortestPath[len(shortestPath)-1][1]

return pathList
```

Note that I couldn't find a copy of `pygraphlib`, seeing as it is no longer under development, so I couldn't test the above code. It should work, mod the syntax uncertainty.  Also, if possible, I would recommend using `networkx`<sup>[[link](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html)]</sup> for any kind of graph manipulation in python, as it is more complete, under active development, and more completely documented then `pygraphlib`.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: But Dijkstra's algorithm calculates the shortest path... how can i account for the sum of the edges being within a certain range? not max or min?

Comment: @majdal Oh, I'm sorry, I've fixed the solution.